# Pyspark how to remove punctuation marks and make lowercase letters in Rdd?

Tags: pyspark, lowercase, punctuation

I would like to remove punctuation mark and make the lowercase letters in RDD? 
Below is my data set

```
 l=sc.parallelize(["How are you","Hello\ then% you"\
,"I think he's fine+ COMING"])
```

I tried below function but I got an error message

```
punc='!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

def lower_clean_str(x):
    lowercased_str = x.lower()
    clean_str = lowercased_str.translate(punc) 
    return clean_str

one_RDD = l.flatMap(lambda x: lower_clean_str(x).split())
one_RDD.collect()
```

But this gives me an error. What might be the problem? How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the python translate function in a wrong way. 
As I am not sure if you are using python 2.7 or python 3, I am suggesting an alternate approach.

The translate function changes a bit in python 3.

The following code will work irrespective of the python version.

```
def lower_clean_str(x):
  punc='!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
  lowercased_str = x.lower()
  for ch in punc:
    lowercased_str = lowercased_str.replace(ch, '')
  return lowercased_str

l=sc.parallelize(["How are you","Hello\ then% you","I think he's fine+ COMING"])
one_RDD = l.map(lower_clean_str)
one_RDD.collect()
```

Output :

> ['how are you', 'hello then you', 'i think hes fine coming']

Comment: @melik welcome to stackoverflow. here you can accept the answer if it works for you, so other stumbled upon this can understand if solution is working or not